# How to validate if the textfield input is equal to the object's name property?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm creating a "guess that pokemon" game using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.  It's very simple.  Displays an image of a pokemon and a textbox that will take user input.  How would I check the textbox value against the pokemon's name?
The Pokemon class has String name and String image (for the image url)

Code used with the "displayPokemon.html" file

```
@GetMapping("/play")
public String play(Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {
   
    Pokemon pokemon = p.getPokemon();

    model.addAttribute("pokemon", pokemon);
        return "displayPokemon";
    }
```

The .html file for displaying the pokemon and the textfield

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Guess that Pokemon v1.0</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<img th:src="${pokemon.image}"/>
<h1>Who's That Pokemon?!</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/play}" th:object="${pokemon}" method="post">
  <p>Guess: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name" placeholder="Name" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the current @PostMapping.  It displays the input from the textfield but that is all.

```
    @PostMapping("/play")
    public String checkPokemonSubmit(@ModelAttribute Pokemon pokemon, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("pokemon", pokemon);
    return "simpleResult";
    }
```

The simpleResult.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Guess that Pokemon - Result</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'Name: ' + ${pokemon.name}" />
<a href="/play">Guess Another Pokemon</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, the textfield is pre-filled with the pokemon's name upon hitting the /play endpoint.  I'd like to have the field be empty then check the input in the field against the pokemon.name from the image it is displaying.  Hopefully that makes sense.  If any other info is needed, I'd be happy to grab it for you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to create a dedicated object to store the answer of the user.

Start by updating your `@GetMapping` to something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/play")
public String play(Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {
   
    Pokemon pokemon = p.getPokemon();

    model.addAttribute("pokemonImage", pokemon.getImage());
    model.addAttribute("answer", new AnswerFormData());
        return "displayPokemon";
    }
```

This makes sure there is an "empty" `AnswerFormData` instance for Thymeleaf to bind with the form in your HTML.

With `AnswerFormData`:

```
public class AnswerFormData {
  private String name;

  // add getter and setter
}
```

Update your template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Guess that Pokemon v1.0</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<img th:src="${pokemonImage}"/>
<h1>Who's That Pokemon?!</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/play}" th:object="${answer}" method="post">
  <p>Guess: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name" placeholder="Name" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, update the `@PostMapping` like this:

```
@PostMapping("/play")
    public String checkPokemonSubmit(@ModelAttribute("answer") AnswerFormData answer, Model model) {

    // Compare answer.getName() with the name of the pokemon here
    // You can add both the given name and the actual name as separate attributes to the model so the Thymeleaf template can show those

    model.addAttribute("pokemon", pokemon);
    model.addAttribute("answer", answer);

    // It is probably better to use "redirect:/result" to force the browser to do a GET request
    return "simpleResult";
    }
```

See also [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/)

Comment: In the @PostMapping, I tried to implement the code and I am able to pass the "answer" from the textfield over to the results page but the "pokemon" is always returning null.  I've tried a few different ways to get the pokemon object referenced as well and have had no success.

Comment: Where do you get the pokemon from in the `@GetMapping` ?

Comment: I create an instance of the pokemon prior to the GetMapping.  I don't think it's best practice to do something like that because I'm very new to Spring still.  I create an instance and then use my method ".getPokemon" in the GetMapping that will call the pokeapi and return a pokemon object from the api service.  I then use that pokemon to be displayed in the GetMapping.  I don't know how to work with the pokemon though in the @PostMapping.  If I call .getPokemon() again, it'll generate a new name/image and not the original from the GetMapping.